# fail fast iterator implementation

Tags: java, iterator

There are similar questions but not exactly what I want to ask. 
I want to ask how Iterator checks for the modification.

[This link](http://www.journaldev.com/378/how-to-avoid-concurrentmodificationexception-when-using-an-iterator) says that its implementation is present in AbstractList class where an int variable modCount is defined that provides the number of times list size has been changed. This value is used in every next() call to check for any modifications in a function checkForComodification().

But I could not really understand it.  If the value is checked only after every next call then if I do a remove followed by add in the same call, size won't change and modCount should not change as well. But removing and adding in the same loop iteration also throws exception.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you look at the code for a `Collection` implementation, lets pick `ArrayList`; we have a `modCount` variable declared in `AbstractList`:

```
protected transient int modCount = 0;
```

And then in each and every modifying method (for example `remove`) for the `ArrayList` we have

```
public E remove(int index) {
    rangeCheck(index);

    modCount++;
    //....
```

So the `modCount` is only ever *incremented*; it is **never** decremented.

In the `Iterator` we then have:

```
final void checkForComodification() {
    if (modCount != expectedModCount)
        throw new ConcurrentModificationException();
}
```

Where `expectedModCount` is a snapshot of the `modCount` taken at `Iterator` creation.

So if there is **any** modification to the underlying `List` while the same instance of an `Iterator` is in use then a `ConcurrentModificationException` will be thrown.

I suppose there is a corner case where if you carried out *enough* modifications then the `int` would overflow and return to it's original value again - this would be a rather large number or modifications however; 2<sup>32</sup> to be precise.

Answer (score 6):

`modCount` always increases when the list is modified (hence *mod* count) so it should also increase when there's a removal.
Thus it would increase on both the remove and add call.

As Boris the Spider said there is the corner case that `modCount` overflows, you can see it by doing:

```
List<Integer> nums = new ArrayList<>();
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) nums.add(i);
for(int n : nums) {
    System.out.println(n);
    for(int i = -1; i < Integer.MAX_VALUE; i++) {
        nums.add(i);
        nums.remove(nums.size() - 1);
    }
}
```

Which will (slowly) print 0 through 9 without throwing any exception.

Comment: +1, It does. But you don't need to assume, the [code is available](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/util/AbstractList.java#AbstractList.0modCount).